# Getting object value from form fields

Tags: php, form

when i do a var dump of ($fields), i get this. i am trying to get the object element => @attributes => article

```
protected 'autofocus' => boolean false
  protected 'element' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[570]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array (size=9)
          'name' => string 'terms' (length=5)
          'type' => string 'terms' (length=5)
          'label' => string 'PLG_USER_TERMS_FIELD_LABEL' (length=26)
          'description' => string 'PLG_USER_TERMS_FIELD_DESC' (length=25)
          'default' => string '0' (length=1)
          'filter' => string 'integer' (length=7)
          'required' => string 'true' (length=4)
          'article' => string '6' (length=1)
          'note' => string '' (length=0)
```

tried `echo $field->element['article']`

How do i get the value of 6 for article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Joomla\CMS\Form\FormField::getAttribute()`](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Form.FormField.html#method_getAttribute) method:

```
$field->getAttribute('article');
```

Comment: worked like a charm